# Remove network drive from Quick Access panel

Tags: windows-10, network-drive

From `This PC` I can see all my network drives, except for one, which is listed in the `Quick Access panel`: `192.168.0.20`

I am unable to remove it from the `Quick Access panel`. It's also impossible to access the network drive, as I'm not in the 192.168.0.20 network.[image]

Comment: Is this the error you get when you right click and click on 'Remove from quick access', or when you left click on it?

Comment: @Jonno, it's a left click, but that's because I'm not in the network. When I right click on it, the only option that's visible is Expand, but I can't click that either. On the screenshot, you see that the top is also greyed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this isn't actually `pinned` to your quick access panel, it's likely showing as it was, at some point, used often enough to class as 'frequently used'. To remove it:

1. Right click on Quick access and choose `Options`
2. Uncheck `Show frequently used folders in Quick access`
3. Click `OK`
4. The item should be gone - redo the procedure checking the box if you wish for Quick access to keep track of folders going forward.

Comment: Wow, such an easy fix, I feel stupid ... Thank you very much!

Comment: Note that this removes the functionality altogether of adding frequently used places in quick access.

Comment: @Thomas - Step 4 (The item should be gone - *redo the procedure checking the box if you wish for Quick access to keep track of folders going forward*.)

Comment: Oh, I did indeed overlook that part, my bad ... though there's an option to clean up all the recent documents & folder too, which may be closer to what this person wants. I'm actually looking specifically for a way to prevent specific drives to show up in recent documents / folders.